# How can I set the default bash/zsh mode to vi command mode instead of vi insert mode?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

So in my bash/zsh terminals I have the `set -o vi`. But then I need to press ESC to get into command mode. I can't figure out how I could make that command mode the default behavior?

Comment: Command mode seems more useful on a non-empty command line; why do you want to make it the default?

Comment: pressing 'i' is easier than reaching out to 'ESC' (especially on my Kinessis keyboard)...

Comment: You can change the key used to enter command mode to something other than Escape. I mention this because the documentation for `bind-key` in `man zshzle` mention not being able to link  `vicmd` to `main`, as you would not be able to switch from `viins` to `vicmd` (presumably after switching to `viins` the first time).

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that behaviour with 'xdotool'.
Install it and add this to your ~/.bashrc then

```
set -o vi
xdotool key Escape
```

Comment: yes, it should only be executed, when the $DISPLAY variable is set. maybe there is a more universal way to emulate the input.